Data lables not working proper in node + ts
I have used chart js to generate chart image in node + ts and generate bar chart for that bar chart i want data labels at the end of the chart but that is not working properly i have used below config for data labels but some time it's showing at the start and sometimes showing at the end of bar and also in my local server it;s working proper while in development server it's not working proper
        `datalabels: {
                            anchor: 'start', 
                            align: 'start',  
                            color: '#fff',
                            font : {
                                weight : 800,
                                size : 16.
                            },
                            textAlign : 'start',
                            padding : 0,
                             formatter: (value) => {
                                if (value != 0) {
                                    return ((value)?.toFixed(2));
                                } else {
                                    return  '';
                                }
                            },
                        },`

datalabels: { anchor: 'start',  align: 'start',   color: '#fff', font : { weight : 800, size : 16. }, textAlign : 'start', padding : 0, formatter: (value) => { if (value != 0) { return ((value)?.toFixed(2)); } else { return  ''; } }, },
tried this config for data lables

here is the link of difference check both

